# Lookup by an arbitrary identifier in MSMQ?

Tags: msmq

Is there a way to assign an identifier to a message in MSMQ, then later locate that message (if it's still in the queue) by that identifier?

Being more specific, it need to be a unique identifier under my control, not something assigned by MSMQ.

Comment: I know it's assigned by MSMQ but can't you use the LookupID? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.lookupid.aspx

Comment: @John LookupID is not accessible until the message has been sent. I assume OP tries to find messages by an identifier he created befor the message was sent.

Comment: @Filburt We need more detail from Badaro.

Comment: @John It's exactly what Filburt suggested, the identifier needs to be created before the message is placed in MSMQ. Otherwise I'd just use LookupID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [messages Label property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.label.aspx) if you want to use an identifier that is created before the message is sent.

The [message LookupID identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.lookupid.aspx) is not accessible until the message has been sent.

Comment: Is there a direct way to do a Peek/Receive using the Label? Or are you suggesting that I enumerate through the messages looking for that particular label?

Comment: No, you'd have to use cursors to search through the queue for a matching label.
One of the reasons the product team introduced LookupID :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's it's pretty much what I already did as a temporary solution. I was hoping there was a better way of doing this.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as it is, but I'd appreciate if you could complement it with the information John provided, so we can leave a more detailed response for anyone searching for this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use CorrelationId?

```
var message = new Message(new Messageval(), new BinaryMessageFormatter());
message.CorrelationId = messageId;
queue.Send(message);
```

And then retrieve the message like this:

```
var resp = (Messageval) queue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(messageId,
                                                     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
                             .Body;
```

The CorrelationId needs to consist of exactly 20 bytes or else an exception will be thrown upon assignment.

Comment: Note that `ReceiveByCorrelationId` or `ReceiveById` are very slow on systems with heavy load [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167049/awful-msmq-performance-using-receivebyid). The only way to have a performant solution in this case is `LookupId`.